# How to add parameters to fl_image in MoviePy?

Tags: python, moviepy

From what I understand, fl_image accepts a pipeline function that should only accept a single image, i.e.
processedClip = input_file.fl_image(imagePipeline)

where

def imagePipeline(img):

....

return finalImage

But what if our imagePipeline function takes in more arguments

i.e.

def imagePipeline(img, arg1, arg2, arg3):

...

return finalImage

How can we add arguments to our imagePipeline in fl_image?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `lambda` trick:

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

def change_image(image, param):
    return image + param

myparam = 1
modified_clip = (
   VideoFileClip('/path/to/my/initial/clip')
   .fl_image(lambda image: change_image(image, myparam))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same trouble and solved it with class.

```python
class ProcessImage:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
    def __call__(self, image):
        # any process you want
        return image

clip = VideoFileClip('input.mp4')
final_clip = clip.fl_image(ProcessImage(1, 2))
final_clip.write_videofile('output.mp4')
```

Comment: THIS. Saw the first answer and was stuck on it for almost an hour and a half until I gave up and decided to check out other approaches. Even chatGPT could not help haha

Answer (score 0):

While this may not be the best solution, you can set whatever parameters you have as global variables.

Eg:

```
param1 = 34
param2 = 43

def process_image(img):
    global param1
    global param2
    if param1 > param2:
        #do whatever
        param1 = param2 * 2
    return image

clip1 = VideoFileClip("input.mp4")
final_clip = clip1.fl_image(process_image)
final_clip.write_videofile('output.mp4', audio=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a closure (less boilerplate than a class):

```
def mkproc(*args,*kw):
    def fun(img):
        #this code has access to args and kw
        return img
    return fun

final = clip.fl_image(mkproc("foo","bar",spam="eggs"))
```

functools.partial does this too. For example:

```
import functools
import cv2

blur5 = functools.partial(cv2.GaussianBlur,ksize=(5,5),sigmaX=0)
```